# Cannot install blockchain_parser getting 'legacy-install-failure'

Tags: python, parsing, blockchain, bitcoin

I am working on a code which will require me to parse the bitcoin data for that i am using blockchain parser package which i found from the github repo below

https://github.com/alecalve/python-bitcoin-blockchain-parser

I tried installing pip3 install blockchain_parse and i also tried pip3 install plyvel and i am only getting the following error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting blockchain_parser
  Using cached blockchain_parser-0.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-bitcoinlib==0.11.0 in /Users/krina/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from blockchain_parser) (0.11.0)
Collecting plyvel==1.2.0
  Using cached plyvel-1.2.0.tar.gz (145 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: plyvel
  Building wheel for plyvel (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/plyvel
      copying plyvel/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/plyvel
      copying plyvel/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/plyvel
      running build_ext
      building 'plyvel._plyvel' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/plyvel
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -c plyvel/_plyvel.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/plyvel/_plyvel.o -Wall -g -x c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
      plyvel/_plyvel.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
      #include "Python.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for plyvel
  Running setup.py clean for plyvel
Failed to build plyvel
Installing collected packages: plyvel, blockchain_parser
  Running setup.py install for plyvel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for plyvel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      running install
      /Users/krina/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/plyvel
      copying plyvel/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/plyvel
      copying plyvel/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/plyvel
      running build_ext
      building 'plyvel._plyvel' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/plyvel
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -c plyvel/_plyvel.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/plyvel/_plyvel.o -Wall -g -x c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
      plyvel/_plyvel.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
      #include "Python.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> plyvel

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I tried to create a virtual environment as well which is also not working.

Can someone make me understand what is wrong here and how can i solve it and if there are any other blockchain parsers that i can use. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

blockchain-parser only supports plyvel 1.2.0
plyvel 1.2.0 only support Python 3.8
Please check your python version is correct.
https://plyvel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/news.html

Try this:

```
brew install leveldb
pip install plyvel==1.2.0
pip install blockchain-parser
```